# How to have just the time picker in a bootstrap 3 date/time picker widget with an added string in format

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, eonasdan-datetimepicker

My question refers to the following bootstrap 3 date time picker:

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I have a bootstrap 3 date and time picker widget on a website, but would actually like it to be just a time picker.

This is normally trivial to achieve, and can be done using the format parameter as follows:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({defaultDate:'now',ignoreReadonly: true});
$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").format('LT');
```

Note the *LT* for local time, or you could use:

```
$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").format('HH:mm:ss');
```

Both of these work as we've removed any reference to date.

However, my issue is that I use an additional string in my text field, so my code actually looks like this:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({defaultDate:'now',ignoreReadonly: true});
$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").format('[Departing at:] LT');
```

This comes from my previous question here:

[Add custom text to the output text field in bootstrap datetimepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097158/add-custom-text-to-the-output-text-field-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

This works fine in that the text field shows:

[image]

But it still contains a date widget. How can I remove the date widget?

If this isn't possible, is there a way to have the time widget appear first by default, that would suffice.

I should point out that I have tried removing the

> ```
> defaultDate:'now'
> ```

code in case it was forcing the date picker to appear, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug of the datetimepicker, if you look at the code you will see that it internally uses the [`isEnabled`](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js#L163) function to determine which component to show. The `isEnabled` determines if the date picker should be shown checking if the format contains a `D` (case insensitive). Unfortunately, it does not takes in account string escaping `[]`.

If the `format` option does not contain `Y`, `M`, `d` and `D`, the component will work as expected, as shown in the following example:

```js
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  defaultDate:'now',
  ignoreReadonly: true,
  format: '[abc:] LT'
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group" style = "margin-bottom:4px;">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" readonly='readonly'/>
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="padding: 6px 11.5px;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

I found that is a already known [issue](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1645) and there is a open [pull request](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/pull/1646) that tries to fix it. If you need, you can try to change the libary code locally with the code proposed by the pull request.

Comment: Sir, you are indeed the authority on this library!

Comment: I suppose I could change it to 'Leaving at' instead!

Comment: Thank you Sir, here to help (on stackoverflow you can find also the main developer of this libary). Don't forget to use `eonasdan-datetimepicker` tag instead of `bootstrap-datepicker` when asking about this libary. Anyway I've edited my answer giving the link to the already known issue (and its fix attempt).

Comment: Thanks, I'll grab the pull request and see if that solves it locally for the time being.  Sorry about the tag, I did the same thing last time.  I'll get it right next time! :)