# Using string literals in a moment.js-dependent datepicker messes up some options

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, momentjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using the [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), which is using Momentjs, and in [its documentation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format) it says to refer to [Momentjs's documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for valid formats.

Neither of those documentations explicitly state that I am allowed to use a string literal in the format. The string I want is `at`, so that I can display the datetime as:

`December 31st, 1999 at 23:59`

The string literal does work however, and I have managed to get the date and time picker to work, read the default value correctly, update itself corrently, and submit the correct value, by setting the following `format` option:

`format: "MMMM D, YYYY \\a\\t HH:mm"`

But a consequence of doing this is that the AM/PM button now shows up in the datepicker's UI, even though the time shown in the input element is shown in the 24-hour format (the interface for choosing times shows the 12-hour format, but the resulting output is in 24-hour format).

The datepicker doesn't explicitly offer an option to show the time in a 12-hour or 24-hour format, but instead relies on the `a` in the `format` to display the AM/PM value. This is the `a` that I need in the `at` string, and I cannot get it (or trick it) to not take that as a AM/PM configuration option.

Can I get around this, and keep the literal `at` in my format, while not showing the AM/PM button in the UI?

**Edit regarding the possible duplicate**:

Same as bowheart's suggestion, it doesn't solve what seems like might just be a bug in the end. Escaping the characters works fine, but as a side-effect turns on an unwanted option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom text to the output text field in bootstrap datetimepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097158/add-custom-text-to-the-output-text-field-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Comment: @VincenzoC Same as bowheart's suggestion, it doesn't solve what seems like might just be a bug in the end. Escaping the characters works fine, but as a side-effect turns on an unwanted option.

Comment: I agree with you, I marked it as possible duplicate exactly because both the problem and the proposed solution are the same of the linked post (I simply wanted to give you a link where the same problem is discussed). Anyway I noticed that I posted the wrong link, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43115451/4131048) you can find an answer stating that this is a known issue of the component and there is a link to the open pull request that tries to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're referring to [escaping characters](http://momentjs.com/docs/#escaping-characters) in momentjs?

Anything enclosed in square brackets – `[]` – will be escaped. So:

```
$('#my-picker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MMMM D, YYYY [at] HH:mm'
})
```

should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the same thing happens unfortunately. I do get the `at` in the output, but the datepicker still shows the AM/PM button. I guess it might be more of the datepicker plugin's fault, than merely correctly using the Momentjs format.

Comment: Ah, you mean the `togglePeriod` button. Then your answer is yes, this is a shortcoming of the plugin. Submit a pull request, find a different one, or make your own.