# Bootstrap datetimepicker v4.x 12hr time not working

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have been trying to get the datetimepicker of bootstrap v4.17.47 working to no avail.  When I set the `format`, I get only a 24 hour and minute, I can't seem to get a 12 hour time to work.

Is there something else that needs to be setup? I'm sing bootstrap v3.3.2, and jQuery v2.2.3.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='TheTime'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below the JavaScript I set, but I don't get a popup that is 12 hours. With the below set, I get a popup that goes to 24 hours, but what appears in the time text box, is for example: pop-up says `21:00`, but the text box shows `9:00 tt`.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#TheTime').datetimepicker({
            format: 'hh:mm tt'
        });                        
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the value of the [`format`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format) option to get a 12 hours popup, simply add an `a`, that as the linked moment docs states represents the `am` / `pm` string.

Here a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#TheTime').datetimepicker({
        format: 'hh:mm a'
    });                        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='TheTime'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you have to display the `tt` text in your input field, take a look here:

- [Add custom text to the output text field in bootstrap datetimepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43097158/4131048)
- [How to have just the time picker in a bootstrap 3 date/time picker widget with an added string in format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43115451/4131048)

Comment: Great! tx u! i didn't see that documented.